# Pythagorean identities

Tags: trigonometry

Eliminate $\theta$ from the following equations:

> $$
> \left \{
>   \begin{align*}
>     X &= 5\cot \theta \\
>     Y &= 4\csc \theta
>   \end{align*}
> \right.$$

This is what I have so far:

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    X &= \frac{5 \cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \\
    Y &= \frac{4}{\sin \theta}
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

$X = 5\cot(\theta)$ ,$ Y = 4 \csc(\theta)$.

Then, $\frac{X}5 = \cot(\theta)$,$\frac{Y}4 = \csc(\theta)$

Since $\csc^2(\theta) = \cot^2(\theta) + 1$, we get:
$$
\bigg(\frac{X}5\bigg)^2 = \bigg(\frac{Y}4\bigg)^2 - 1 \implies 16X^2 = 25Y^2 - 400
$$
Hence, we have eliminated $\theta$ from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for each trig function, then use this identity:
$$
1 + \cot^2 \theta = \csc^2 \theta
$$